# Not Retrieved React Native Firestore Subcollection

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem when i want to get subcollections.
Can anybody help me, please ?

**firestore structure :**

```
questions(collection) ->  curretUser.id(doc) -> questions(collection) -> questionIDautoCreated(doc)-> {title: "", description: "" }
```

**And i try to get data:**

```
return (dispatch) => {
  firebase.firestore().collection('questions').doc(currentUser.uid)
  .collection('questions').get()
  .then((documentSnapshot) => {
    const value = documentSnapshot.data();
    console.log('Value Succeed : ');
    console.log(value);
  });
};
```

**Error :**

***Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id:0)***
**Type Error: documentSnapshot.data is not a function**

Thank You

Comment: Sorry @Cœur :( thank you for your notice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because collection is not a `DocumentSnapshot`, its a `QuerySnapshot`. Collection contains a list of data, it is not an actual document. 
If you look in the firestore docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data). You can see when querying for collection, you should:

```
querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```

The exception speaks for it self, the object you receive is not the one you expect.

```
return (dispatch) => {
  firebase.firestore().collection('questions').doc(currentUser.uid)
   .collection('questions').get()
   .then((querySnapshot) => {
     querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
       console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
     });
   });
 };
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get subcollections like this,

Collections returns docs array, you must access docs data first.
**Quick Example**

```
firebase.firestore().collection('...').get().then(s => console.log(s.docs))
```

**Your solution**

```
return (dispatch) => {
    firebase.firestore().collection(`questions/${currentUser.id}/questions`)
      .get()
      .then(questionSnapshot => questionSnapshot.docs)
      .then(questions => {
        questions.forEach(question => {
          console.log(question)
        })
      })
  }
```